# centering the content of this wordpress page

Tags: html, wordpress, css, center, centering

i'm trying to center all of the products on this wordpress page so that everything is aligned centrally, i tried wrapping it all in a div with the following CSS but what this did was wrap the contents to the middle but the products where still left aligned to that.

```
#big-center {
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: box;

-webkit-box-orient: block-axis;
-moz-box-orient: block-axis;
box-orient: block-axis;

-webkit-box-align: center;
-moz-box-align: center;
box-align: center;

-webkit-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-pack: center;
box-pack: center;
}
```

I wonder if anyone has any advise or if there is something i'm missing to do this?

here is a link to the page: http://bit.ly/ObdhUm

Comment: please add the html code so we can assist....

Comment: You will need to provide a link to the page or more html/css code. Otherwise it would be very hard to know what is causing that.

Comment: Thank you sorry, here is a link to the page :) [link]http://bit.ly/ObdhUm